# How to execute a function parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a *generic* method that will take a `Func` parameter.

traditional func is that we create `methodOne()` and send it as a *parameter* to another method. However, that will defeat the purpose of making the method I am trying to create as a *generic*.

**My code:**

```
public static List<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string connection, 
                                      string commandText, 
                                      Func<SqlDataReader, List<T>> myMethodName)
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    items = myMethodName(sqlDataReader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (sqlDataReader != null) sqlDataReader.Close();

                    cmd.Dispose();

                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (sqlDataReader != null) sqlDataReader.Dispose();

                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return items;
}
```

**Trying to call the method above like this**:

```
    public List<Function> GetDeletedFunctions(string connectionString)
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;
        List<Function> functions;

        string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM Table "; // dumy query

        functions = DbHelper.ExecuteQuery<Function>(
          connectionString, 
          cmdText, 
          List<Function>(sqlDataReader)
        {

            var f =
            (from x in sqlDataReader.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
             select new Function
             {
                 Param1 = DbHelper.GetValue<string>("Param1 ", x),
                 Param2 = DbHelper.GetValue<string>("Param2", x),
             }).ToList();

            return f;
        } );
}
```

**Compile Time Error:**

> Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'List' cannot be used like a
>   method.

I am assuming there is a *syntax issue* here and its driving me nuts. Any suggestions?

Comment: First off you don´t assign anything to your `sqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When wrapping into `using` you don't have to catch exceptions (.Net will free resources for you, rain on shine)

```
// Dangerous practice: what if I put commandText "drop table MyTable"?
public static List<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string connection, 
                                      string commandText, 
                                      Func<SqlDataReader, List<T>> myMethodName) {
  //ToDo: Validate parameters here

  using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection)) {
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con)) {
      // IDataReader is IDisposable as well       
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        return myMethodName(reader);
      } 
    }
  }  
}
```

Then all we have to do is to provide arguments: `connectionString`, `commandText` and map function; let's do it:

```
public List<Function> GetDeletedFunctions(string connectionString) {
  //TODO: Validate connectionString here 

  return DbHelper.ExecuteQuery<Function>(
     connectionString,                                // Connection String
   @"SELECT * FROM Table ",                           // Query
    (reader) => {                                     // Map function
       // When given reader, the map function creates list
       List<Function> result = new List<Function>();

       // Convert each record into Function instance and add them into the list
       while (reader.Read()) {
         Function item = new Function() {
           Param1 = Convert.ToString(reader["Param1"]),
           Param2 = Convert.ToString(reader["Param2"]),
         }

         result.Add(item); 
       }

       // and return the list
       return result;
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you, If I could just bother you with one thing: " (reader) => " this syntax is the equivalent of? and also the "reader" does not exist as a parameter anywhere in the code but I am not getting any errors, how come?

Comment: reader is a parameter being passed to a function written after => (Lambda Expression)

Comment: `(reader) => {body}` is typical syntax of a lambda function where `reader` is *formal parameter* (you can change it into, say, `r`)

Comment: Again thank you! tend to use lambada expressions when doing the linq queries but never done it as a function like this.

Comment: Just curious, is this possible to solve without a lambda function?

Comment: @ThunD3eR: *delegate* is a typical alternative to *lambda function*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in the way you are trying to pass function as parameter. Please use the following code:

```
public List<Function> GetDeletedFunctions(string connectionString)
{                        
    string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM Table "; // dumy query
    return DbHelper.ExecuteQuery<Function>(connectionString,
                                           cmdText,
                                           (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader) =>
                                           {
                                               var f = (from x in sqlDataReader.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
                                               select new Function
                                               {
                                                   Param1 = DbHelper.GetValue<string>("Param1 ", x),
                                                   Param2 = DbHelper.GetValue<string>("Param2", x)
                                               }).ToList();

                                               return f;
                                           });
}
```